# Работа с php api и его зашита

Tags: php, android, api

Здравствуете у меня ест сервер и база данных и готовый api. Надо создать приложения в android, работа с api управлять база данных. Но проблема в том что клиент могут декомпилировать приложения и спокойно увидит адрес api как

```
private void getResponce(){
   final Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://localhost/api/welcome.php?user_login=1&user_password=1").build();
   client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
       @Override
       public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           });
       }

       @Override
       public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response){
           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   try {
                       Toast.makeText(context, response.body().string(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           });
       }
   });
}
```

вопрос: Как работать с api безопасно и надежно

Comment: а что такого в том, что они увидят адрес api ? что именно Вы защитить хотите ? адрес ? или все таки что-то другое ?

Comment: используйте аутентификацию сертификатами x509

Comment: Хочу защитит api

Comment: От чего это будет защита? Если приложение извлекает данные, значит любой кто повторит запрос эти данные так же получат))

Comment: От чего это будет защита?  "http://1.1.1.1/api/welcome.php?user_login=1&user_password=1"

Comment: В приложения написана несколько адрес api например http://1.1.1.1/api/update.php?user_id=1&user_price=20000

Comment: Я спокойно могу декомп приложения и получаю это адрес api 1.1.1.1/api/update.php?user_id=100000&user_price=20000000000000

Comment: Адрес можно увидеть и без декомпиляции на любом узле сети по пути от клиента до сервера. Защититься от этого нельзя и поэтому передавать пароли в адресе однозначно не стоит. Любая защита на стороне клиента - всего лишь препятствие для чайников. Защищаться нужно на сервере - именно для этого и делают API, чтобы клиент не имел прямого доступа к данным, а получал через API только то, что ему дозволено.

Comment: Тогда как могу правильно защитить api

Comment: Создаете токен который присваиваите юзеру, по этому токену на сервере идентифицируете пользователя и уровень его доступа к ресурсам сайта. Если у пользователя установлено приложение то он и так имеет доступ к апи и если он декомпилирует приложение то получит доступ к адресу и данным к которым он и так имеет доступ. Вместо `user_id=100000` у вас будет `user_token=набор_произвльных_символов` тогда подобрать токен будет намного сложнее чем просто поменять цифру и получить доступ к данным пользователя с другим айди.